# Is it possible to use a Ledger with cleos?

Tags: cleos, private-key

I would like to protect my dApp production keys. Is it possible to use Ledger to protect my private keys and deploy with cleos? I would like my private key to remain on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements, if you require a deterministic key that can be used outside of the device there are workarounds, however if you require the private keys remain on the device, the only way to do that is to have the device sign an unsigned transaction as one would a cold wallet.

If you can use the ledger to sign a JSON transaction, then perhaps you could use cleos to just broadcast the signed transaction.

Update:
you can export your transaction by using the following syntax,

```
cleos push action -s -d -j contract action {} -p user@active
```

it will output a JSON block of code you can put into a file, and sign the transaction with your ledger, when you have your signatures you can then push the transaction using,

```
cleos push transaction "$(cat transaction.json)"
```

Comment: How can I provide the signature to the cleos push transaction command?

Comment: You need to copy and paste the signature into the transaction json, inserting it into the the part that reads "signature":[]  in my example push code you are inserting a json file from the filesystem using cat